# VowpalWabbit - how to set third order interactions only for categorical features for tabular data with both continues and categorical features

Tags: python, feature-extraction, feature-selection, feature-engineering, vowpalwabbit

for VowpalWabbit - how to set third order interactions only for categorical features for tabular data with both continues and categorical features , for example how to change : vw_squared = VWRegressor(loss_function='squared' , interactions = 'abc')

Let say input data to VWRegressor is pandas data frame where categorical features are market as category type, like

'''

```
df['jobcat']=df['job'].astype('category').cat.codes
df['educationcat']=df['education'].astype('category').cat.codes
df['defaultcat']=df['default'].astype('category').cat.codes
```

'''

Answer (score 0):

You can put the categorical data under different namespaces than the non categorical data, and then assign interactions for those namespaces only. Right now there is no automatic way to do that so it has to be done manually by separating the features you want to interact into separate namespaces.